# How to use binomial family for non-integers in GLMMTMB?

Tags: r, statistics, glmmtmb

Here's my model:

`revisitsm0 <- glmmTMB(cbind(revisits_per_bout, tot_visits_bout - revisits_per_bout) ~ experiment_type * foraging_bout + (1|colony/bee_id), data=table_training, family=binomial)`

My model doesn't fit so well because of dispersion, so I square-rooted my variables "revisits_per_bout" and "tot_visits_bout", hence giving me non-integers.

Since quasibinomial is not available in GLMMTMB, how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This really belongs on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), because it is a question of "what to do" more than "how to do it".

- `family = "betabinomial"` should be the simplest way to handle overdispersion (I would **not** recommend transforming the response variable. It is a good rule of thumb that if you have count-type (non-negative integer) responses, it's best to model them on the original scale).
- if overdispersion seems to be associated with particular predictors (e.g. dispersion is different for different experiment types, even after taking the mean-variance relationship of the beta-binomial into account; you can use the location-scale plot [`sqrt(abs(pearson_resids))` vs. the predictor of interest) to assess this, you can use `family = "betabinomial"` plus a `dispformula =`  argument
- you could also use an observation-level random effect
- you can also do a *post hoc* conversion of a binomial fit to a quasi-binomial fit following  the recipe in the [GLMM FAQ 'fitting models with overdispersion' section](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#fitting-models-with-overdispersion) (this link has more general advice/info on methods for dealing with overdispersion)